# Deleted .aae files and now the related photos are gone

Tags: ios, photos, iphone

I was manually copying my photos from my iPhone 6 running iOS 9.3.1 onto my Windows 8 laptop and deleted all the `.aae` files associated with the various JPEGs before copying them over. I immediately found that the JPEGs associated with the `.aae` files were rendered unmovable and inaccessible.

I understand that `.aae` files are used to keep a history of photo modifications so that one can revert if one wants in the future, but I didn't think they were integral to accessing my JPEGs as I've been able to delete them AFTER transferring them to my laptop before without issue.

So now, I have a load of great pics I can't transfer and can't access.

I also tried unplugging and replugging my iPhone to my laptop, but now the once-inaccessible JPEGs seem to have totally gone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Why not restore your phone from a backup? Are you looking to do data recovery or just wipe the camera roll and start over? By editing this to narrow down what you intend to do, it's far more likely someone will offer an answer.

Comment: Other option would be in the future to copy all contents of the Camera Roll onto a folder in your computer and delete the .aae inside this folder, after copying them, which wouldn't probably delete the JPEGs